# BroadcastReceiver: how to manage priority?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

How is the priority setting for a `BroadcastReceiver` to be used?

How could my application possibly know the priorities of all other `BroadcastReceivers` in the apps that a phone user might have installed?

I have an app with a `BroadcastReceiver` to just intercept one number of interest. For all other numbers I immediately call `setResultData` with the original number and return.

The app worked fine, until a user with an Asus phone and automatic recording of phone calls (an Asus feature) enabled. For this user, my app is not called. I don't think Asus would be writing a rogue app. What could possibly explain the phenomena?

Comment: See [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) link. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the line "The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000." from below link, highest priority is 999 not 1000.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer my question. What number should I use when I don't know what other `BroadcastReceiver` apps have been installed in the phone and what their priorities are?